# Detect Javascript/Ajax Change in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, uiwebview

I am trying to check to see if a certain page has loaded for my users.  The user goes through a signup process in a UIWebView and I would like to know when it is completed.  The problem is the signup doesn't change the webpage, it uses Javascript and Ajax to update the content on the screen.  So running:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText;"];
```

In `webViewDidStartLoad` only returns on the first load of the initial site.  Basically I just want to check the text on the page whenever it changes to string match something like "Success" and then I would know that the user has successfully logged in.  Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  In javacript on your page do something like this

```
window.location = 'myprotocol://userDidSignUp'
```

Then in your UIWebViewDelegate do

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(request == nil)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    NSString* urlStr = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if(urlStr != nil && [urlStr isEqualToString:@"myprotocol://userDidSignUp")
    {
        //User signed in
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not signing up to a website controlled by me

Comment: You can write javascript to check the DOM to see if some text has changed and run it with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` and you could run that every 1-2 seconds.  I am not sure though, if that is the best solution.

Comment: Ya that is what I am doing.  It works, but wondering if there was a more efficient solution.  Thanks for your help!